# Exporting amounts using space as '000 delimiter

Tags: pandas, formatting, xlsxwriter

I would like all amounts exported to Excel to use space as '000 delimiter and ',' for decimal. E.g: "3 257 132,54" (common number format in Europe)

I tried to adapt the example provided on `xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io` :

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
```

As follows

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '# ##0,00'})
```

I am using the code from the `xlsxwriter` doc. I just modified the '000 delimiter and the decimal point:

```
# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)
```

I obtain a very surprising result. The example provided above will appear,in Excel, as: 3257 132,54.
Almost good, but the '000 separator is only used once for thousands, but not for millions or billions. (nb: the comma as decimal separator works fine)

Is there a trick I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use whatever number format that you would use in Excel for this. Probably something like `### ### ###.00` (although it doesn't have a comma for a decimal):

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '### ### ###.00'})

worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)

worksheet.write(0, 1, 123.123)
worksheet.write(1, 1, 1234.123)
worksheet.write(2, 1, 12345.123)
worksheet.write(3, 1, 123456.123)
worksheet.write(4, 1, 1234567.123)
worksheet.write(5, 1, 12345678.123)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

You can find the exact number format you need by setting it in Excel and then checking what it is in the custom section of the number format dialog.

Comment: Thanks. This is a workaround that will make the trick. 
I looked at the customer section of the number format dialog. It exactly matches the format I provided ('# ##0,00'). 
It seems that there is a difference between Excel and Excelwriter: i
n Excel, the '000 delimiter is applied in a general manner (to millions, billions, etc...). In ExcelWriter, you need to specify the format ('### ### ###.00') if the delimiter is space, but not if it's a comma. Then, the comma is propagated properly to the millions and billions.

Altogether, it looks like a bug, if my statements above are true...

Comment: Can you try `'num_format': 4` (where 4 is a number and not a string) to get the Excel built in format for currency style numbers: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-num-format

Comment: The 'num_format' : 4 trick works. I jumped to the xlswriter link. I suppose that this solution refers to the section "Excel’s built-in formats". If this is the case, I did not understand how to use the 'index' provided. The documentation says we should use value '0x04'. In your comments, you asked to use "4 (where 4 is a number and not a string)". I don't get it. How should this index codification work?

Comment: Hexadecimal 0x04 is the same as Decimal 4. Either one will work since the are the same numeric value.

Comment: Perfectly  clear, now. The point is solved, and I now better understand the xlsxwriter doc itself. Thanks for this.